# how to create a TDengine cluster in one server?

Tags: database, tdengine

I need to deploy a TDengine cluster with 4 nodes for prototype testing, anybody knows how to make it in one server?

Answer (score 0):

In one server, you can start multiple taosd in different ports like 6030-6041, 7030-7041, 8030-8041, ... and also set all firstEp of each taosd to the same master node